# in jQuery Mobile, how to set a data-transition for a group of links?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I would like to change the data-transition for all links in specific sections. The docs on jQuery Mobile page transitions (http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/docs-transitions.html) only specify how to set a transition type on a per-element basis by using an attribute.

I would prefer to manage interaction behavior entirely in the javascript layer, rather than the content. Setting an option for $.mobile.changePage() for a group of elements would be ideal, but I have not been able to figure out how to do that.

jQuery Mobile docs attribute example:

```
<a href="index.html" data-transition="pop">I'll pop</a>
```

If limited to setting data-transition by an attribute, it would be great if I could specify the transition on a parent element ('flip'):

```
<ul data-transition="flip">
    <li><a href="page1.html">I'll flip</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html">I'll flip too</a></li>
    <li><a href="page3.html">I'll flip as well</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="another_page.html">I'll use the default transition (eg slide)</a>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be how it works.

Currently my best solution is to add the section-specific data-transition attribute to all links within the appropriate section with javascript, but would prefer to handle this in a more performant manner. jQuery .attr solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul a').attr('data-transition', 'flip');
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED: Much easier implementation

Live Link:

- http://jsfiddle.net/EwyGL/10/

I used flip instead of pop to show the transition a little more, but just replace flip with pop.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1"> 
    <div data-role="content"> 
        <div class="content-primary">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f">
                <li data-role="list-divider">Transition Flip</li> 
                <li><a href="#page1">I'll Flip</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page2">I'll Flip too</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page3">I'll also Flip</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2"> 
    <div data-role="content"> 
        <div class="content-primary">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f">
                <li data-role="list-divider">Transition Flip</li> 
                <li><a href="#page1">I'll Flip</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page2">I'll Flip too</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page3">I'll also Flip</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page3"> 
    <div data-role="content"> 
        <div class="content-primary">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f">
                <li data-role="list-divider">Transition Flip</li> 
                <li><a href="#page1">I'll Flip</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page2">I'll Flip too</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page3">I'll also Flip</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-transition','flip'); 
});
```

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for the response! Question - what do we get out of using .each() instead of just $('a').attr('data-transition','flip'); Thanks!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/each/ "The .each() method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the element."

Comment: using each with added functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/EwyGL/12/ also upvotes and accepted answers are welcome